# How can I get my Facebook dialog to show up when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to add a button to my site that, when clicked, will bring up a Facebook dialog box so the user can post a message to their Facebook timeline.

I've been reading through the documentation I think my code is correct but the button doesn't work.   When I click the button nothing happens.

My code:

```
    <html>

    <body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>

            function post_to_facebook()
            {
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : '********',
                  status     : true,
                  xfbml      : true
                });
                FB.ui(
                  {
                   method: 'feed',
                   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
                   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
                   description: (
                      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
                      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
                      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
                   ),
                   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
                   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
                  },
                  function(response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                      alert('Post was published.');
                    } else {
                      alert('Post was not published.');
                    }
                  }
                );
              };

              (function(d, s, id){
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
               }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            }
        </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="post_to_facebook()" value="Post my score to Facebook" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's a screenshot of my browser after I click the button:
[image]

Comment: you probably want to remove your appId from this post....

Comment: Thanks man, I forgot.

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console? In chrome or firefox click ctrl+shift+i to open developer tools, click on the console tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you testing on a local computer? Try saving the page on a server and then opening it. It should work.

Comment: Ahh yes, I am.  I need to go put it on the correct domain.